# pear --force not recognised

Tags: php, mamp, pear

I'm trying to correct a Notice: Non-static method issue I'm having with pear XML_Util.

*Notice: Non-static method XML_Util::attributesToString() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/leighgrigaliunas/Documents/Websites/schoolhours-apiimport-v3/system/ext/XML/Util.php on line 518*

I know they're not errors as such, but I'd like to get rid of them if possible before cutting the code live.

I thought using XML_Util2 might correct it, however now I am stuck because I can't force the uninstall of XML_Util.  Console_Getopt is stating that -f or --force is not recognised.  I then tried to update Console_Getopt (it's deprecated apparently) to Console_GetoptPlus, but I'm stuck again because I can't uninstall Console_Getopt.

I'm new at this, but I'll try to describe my environment as best I can

MAMP PRO version 3.0.7.3 on OSX 10.10
PHP 5.4.34
Pear 1.9.5 (all packages/channels up to date)

Do I need to provide anything further to get assistance? I've googled the heck out of this and can't get past it.  Please help!

Comment: this isn't something you can fix. the code is fundamentally broken, exactly as the notice says: doing a static all on a non-static method. while this MAY work, if the method doesn't use $this at all, it's not something you should paper over.

Comment: Perhaps think about using composer instead of pear to manage your packages - there's a much wider range of options on http://packagist.org and composer can still pull in old PEAR libs - https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#pear

Comment: why do you have to force uninstallation of xml_util at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's not called `--force` for the uninstall command:

```
$ pear help uninstall
...
--ignore-errors
    force install even if there were errors
```